# When does a structure admit a "bi-elementary" embedding (into anything at all)?

Tags: logic, model-theory

In analogy with the notion of a *bilinear map*, say that a **bi-elementary map** is a function $$f:\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$$ for some structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C}$ such that:

- For each $a\in\mathcal{A}$ the map $l_a^f:b\mapsto f(a,b)$ is an elementary embedding of $\mathcal{B}$ into $\mathcal{C}$.
- For each $b\in\mathcal{B}$ the map $r_b^f:a\mapsto f(a,b)$ is an elementary embedding of $\mathcal{A}$ into $\mathcal{C}$.

In particular, say that a structure $\mathcal{S}$ is **malleable** iff for some structure $\mathcal{T}$ there is a bi-elementary $f:\mathcal{S}\times\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathcal{T}$ *(if it helps to make things more concrete note that we may as well take $\mathcal{T}$ to be some sufficiently saturated model of $Th(\mathcal{S})$)*. Malleability is fairly rare. For example, if $\mathcal{S}$ is malleable then $\mathcal{S}$ has only one $1$-type: if $\mathcal{S}\models\varphi(s)\wedge\neg\varphi(t)$ then for any $f:\mathcal{S}^2\rightarrow\mathcal{S}$ either $\mathcal{S}\models \varphi(f(s,t))$ in which case $l_s^f$ is not elementary as witnessed by $t$ or $\mathcal{S}\models\neg\varphi(f(s,t))$ in which case $r_t^f$ is not elementary as witnessed by $s$. On the other hand, nontrivial malleable structures do exist: for example, $f:\mathbb{Q}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}: (x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is a bi-elementary map when we equip $\mathbb{Q}$ with the ordering alone.

My question is:

> Is there a snappy characterization of malleability?

EDIT: Note that in fact every *group* is bi-interpretable (using a parameter) with a malleable structure - namely, its **torsor reduct**. Given a group $(G; *,\cdot^{-1})$, let $t: G^3\rightarrow G: (a,b,c)\mapsto (a*b^{-1})*c$; the group operation $*$ is then a bi-elementary (indeed, "bi-isomorphic") map $(G;t)\times (G;t)\rightarrow (G;t)$. Since groups can be quite wild, this means that malleability in fact implies very little tameness. And the same argument works for ordered groups as well.

Comment: Interesting question! Do you know any example of a malleable structure that is not a model of one of the five reducts of DLO?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Nope! I don't see a proof that none exist, though, either.

Comment: The random graph is malleable: put a graph structure on $G\times G$ so that $g\mapsto (g,h)$ and $g\mapsto (h,g)$ are embeddings for all $h$, then use the fact that every countable graph embeds in the random graph.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ah, good point. Here's a question: is every malleable structure's theory $\aleph_0$-categorical?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Actually wait. Isn't the "torsor reduct" of an arbitrary group always malleable, via the group operation itself? That is, if $\mathcal{G}=(G;*,\cdot^{-1})$ is a group, let $t:G^3\rightarrow G: (a,b,c)\mapsto (a*b^{-1})*c$. Then the map $$g: G^2\rightarrow G: (a,b)\mapsto a*b$$ seems to me to witness the malleability of $(G; t)$. In fact, each $g(a,-)$ and $g(-,b)$ is an outright automorphism of $(G;t)$. Or am I making a silly mistake?

Comment: Seems right to me!

Comment: @AlexKruckman To be honest, in retrospect the "bi-automorphic" version if this question seems more natural. Oh well :P.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that. But that raises an interesting question: does the random graph admit a bi-automorphism?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I feel like it should. Can't we just do some kind of greedy argument?

Comment: Yeah I think one can equip $\mathbb{Q}$ with a translation-invariant graph structure making it isomorphic to the random graph.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Hey, dopey question: is it even obvious exactly which finite graphs admit bi-automorphisms *(let's call this "affability" since the only examples I can think of feel like affine space somehow, and besides that sounds cute)*?

Comment: It's not obvious to me! I like affability.

Comment: @AlexKruckman OK, now this is stuck in my head. I think this comment thread is getting long, but I'd be interested in thinking about this more; would you be interested/available sometime in the near future for zoom/skype/etc.?

Comment: Sure, send me an email.